# Cheese crackers

Tags: baking

In a recipe using butter, flour, and cheese, what difference will it make to combine the cheese either first with the flour, or later after the butter and flour have been combined?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the butter is rubbed into the flour (as when making pastry), and the cheese is grated firm cheese there will be a difference.

By trying to combine all at once, you'll struggle to rub in all the butter without trying to rub the cheese in as well.  With cold butter it will be really quite awkward.

With a fine grated hard cheese like parmesan you'll be trying to rub the butter into the cheese, but this may still work better than trying to rub the cheese into the flour.

Answer (score -1):

Probaly none to very little, but why temp screwing it up?
You are probably not saving time or effort

Anyroad, the real answer is to try and see what will happen (using a greatly reduced batch size - maybe one quarter?. If it doesn't turn out as expected, you should have learned for the future